# How do I change SOME values in my SQL query result?

Tags: mysql, select, replace

I have a result with a couple hundred rows, and I only want to change 2 values in a specific column.

I have tried

```
CASE GRUPPIERUNGSATTRIBUT08
    WHEN '1043333138' THEN '##########'
    WHEN '1048576018' THEN '##########'
END AS GRUPPIERUNGSATTRIBUT08,
```

but as a result, all of the other values have become (null). Do I need to add an else branch, and if so, how should that look?

Comment: Where do you want to change these 2 values? In the output of the query, or in the database ?

Comment: Can you provide sample data,  table description and expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ELSE, so when its not matched, you put the column value like this :

```
CASE GRUPPIERUNGSATTRIBUT08

WHEN '1043333138' THEN '##########'

WHEN '1048576018' THEN '##########'

else GRUPPIERUNGSATTRIBUT08 

END AS GRUPPIERUNGSATTRIBUT08
```

Comment: perfect, thank you so much !!!!

Comment: glad it helped @HajnalPuskás

Comment: And what if I would like to change a value in a row that looks something like this : ROUND(SUM(AGGREGATSATTRIBUT4)/100,0) ? CASE doesn't work with this :(

Comment: hmmm i didnt get it

Comment: not row... column. sorry.

Comment: @HajnalPuskás i think it doesnt work because you try to use aggregation function : SUM. For better undestanding please show us some example